# Server or clientside date parsing

Tags: mysql, parsing, date

I have to parse dates, the question is not how, but I have to convert: yyyy-mm-dd to for example: today, tomorrow, yesterday etcetera, now my question is, I got two idea's of setting this up con's and pro's, I would like to hear what your opinion is.

So either on PHP or on javascript I get a mysql date (yyyy-mm-dd) and that has to get converted in to (if today "today", if yesterday "yesterday" etcetera) now my question is, if I would do this server side would it cost alot of server load and would it be smart to handle this on the client side?

(per server request to parse aprox 30 dates).

Thanks! :)

Comment: It's really not a heavy load on either side. I would recommend doing it on the server, as a client side (JS) solution would require the DOM to be loaded.

Comment: If there are alot of requests too on the server (100.000 per day) would it still be smart to do it on the server side? I'm just really focussed on scaling atm.

Comment: Yes, it would. It'll cost you practically nothing to convert a date to a human-readable interval.

Answer (score 0):

Client side and with [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

If you have really weak clients (ie phones) consider going it *once* on the server, perhaps each midnight, or to be able to cache it. As load picks up this might be one of those things that end up being a real pain.

Still, put the clients to work with presentation logic, it's where it fits.

Comment: Yes it's also going to have an web app, but since all the cellphone are @ 1ghz at the moment, I might just do it all at the clientside. Timeago is not what I need, I need something that will calculate future instead its for an list of activities of employees for example: Employee X is going to Building A tomorrow, or Employee Y is going to Building B next week Friday, you might also know a solution for that?

Comment: I think timeago supports future dates aswell. Give it a try.